# Error when yarn start: Error parsing bundle asset "D:\A\B\C_D_myfile.css": no such file

Tags: node.js, windows, webpack, babeljs

When I `yarn start` on React Project Root, following error message is shown.

```
Error when yarn start: Error parsing bundle asset "D:\A\B\C_D_myfile.css": no such file
```

But `myfile.css` exists at `D:\A\B\C\D\myfile.css`, so it seems path problem on Windows.

`myfile.css` is used in `await import` like this:

```
await import((`../D/myFile.css`));
```

It seems all slashes(`/`) replaced with `_`.

`.babelrc.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@babel/preset-typescript',
        ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: true } }],
    ],
    plugins: [
        [
            'module-resolver',
            {
                root: ['./src'],
                alias: {
                    '@': './src',
                    '@pc': './src/pc',
                    '@mobile': './src/mobile'
                }
            },
            "babel-plugin-react-scoped-css"
        ]
    ],
};
```

OS: Windows10 
Node: 16.20.0 
Yarn: 3.5.0 
babel-plugin-module-resolver: 5.0.0 
babel-plugin-react-scoped-cs: 1.1.1